# iOS Core Data executeFetchRequest is returning empty object

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdictionary

I'm using Core Data to store an entity which includes a transformable NSDictionary attribute. I can see an object in .SQLite file after I store it, so I think (?) I'm good there. However, when I try to retrieve the entire entity, I get an NSArray with one element [0] that is nil and (of course) crashes when I try to access any attribute.

```
HVBAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Events" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entityDesc];

NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

// [objects count] = 1 but objects[0] = nil

// and the following line crashes of course
NSMutableDictionary *data = objects[0][@"data"];
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

(Note that I have set up an Events class with the NSDictionary property and other properties as well.)

Here's how I set up the entity:

[image]

Events.h:

[image]

Events.m:

[image]

Comment: Check the type of object stored in `objects`. My guess is they are instances of `Events`.

Comment: Does `error` get set, or is it still nil?

Comment: Can you try to print objects. There is a chance that your object is fault.

Comment: "one element that is nil" doesn't make any sense, because `NSArray` cannot contain nil values. What are you actually getting?

Comment: Good questions! NSLogging of [objects class] gives "_PFArray", error gives "(null)" and objects gives "<Events: 0x9074D50> (entity: Events; id: ... , data: <fault>)" Strange that the other properties are not listed. Yes, in the debugger I see the "[0]" element but there's nothing there.

Comment: In your code that ends `NSMutableDictionary *data = objects[0][@"data"];`, do you separately initialise the `NSMutableDictionary` at some point before this line of code?

Comment: Thanks, but that's not necessary if it's being assigning to an object that's already created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out what was going on:

First, the reason that 'objects' had one row, but appeared "empty" was because that is the default behavior. Values will not be retrieved until you specifically ask for them, unless you change that by sending a setReturnsObjectsAsFaults message:

```
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
```

Note that NSLogging the object without this produced "data: ".

Second, and most important, 'objects' is NOT an NSArray of NSDictionarys or NSMutableDictionarys. So while I can replace `[objects objectAtIndex:0]" with "objects[0]`, I can not replace `[objects[0] valueForKey:@"created"]` with `[objects[0][@"created"]`. That's what caused the crash.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Including the crash report would have made this obvious. You don't need to tell it not to return faults, only the second part of your answer is required. `objects` is an array of `Event` objects.

Comment: Right. Newbie mistake!

Comment: It's a fairly common one, don't feel bad :)

Comment: Setting
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
Worked for me. But  without using this also it worked for most of my model that was created in using Xcode 6. But newly created model in xcode 7.2 need  this line. I don't understand.

Comment: What ?!  I've never needed this before (in previous versions of Xcode).  Oh, I really hate this environment.  Thanks for the tip...  unbelievable.

Comment: Interestingly, Apple's own examples don't mention this flag, so they'll also show you how to write code to load blank records from CoreData.  Unbelievable.   https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html

Comment: Seriously! I'm using XCode 9.2, iOS 11.2 Version and I also get an NSArray with objects consist of empty attributes. Just after setting `setReturnsObjectsAsFaults` flag to `NO` it fills all the attributes and everything seems to be fine! What kind of sorcery is this?

Answer (score 0):

Please call willAccessValueForKey: before accessing @"data"

```
[objects[0] willAccessValueForKey:@"data"];
NSMutableDictionary *data = objects[0][@"data"];
[objects[0] didAccessValueForKey:@"data"];
```